# Retrieve a defined field with XDocument

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I'm currently working on an application and I need to be able to configure it through an `XML Document`, I've created the `XML` document but I don't know how to properly access attribute in it. Here's a short example:

```
<MonitoringApplication>
  <Configuration>
    <WebService>
      <HttpUser>User</HttpUser>
      <HttpPassword>Password</HttpPassword>
    </WebService>

    <Application>
      <Server>http://localhost</Server>
      <ServerPort>9000</ServerPort>
    </Application>
  </Configuration>
</MonitoringApplication>
```

I want to be able to retrieve Server or HttpUser just by specifying Server or HttpUser, not the whole structure. Currently I'm trying with this but it's not working:

```
myXmlFile.Element("HttpUser").Value;
```

Where `myXmlFile` is just a document loaded with `XDocument.Load()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty?

```
var user = (string)doc.Descendants("HttpUser").First();
```

To answer your comment, your nodes are now namespaced, so you need to take this into account:

```
var ns = XNamespace.Get("urn:monitoring-schema");
var user = (string)doc.Descendants(ns + "HttpUser").First();
```

Comment: Was just dumb, I wrote HTTP instead of Http in my Unit Test

Comment: I've updated the XML with this `<MonitoringApplication xmlns="urn:monitoring-schema">` and now this solution is not working anymore

Answer (score 1):

You can do this.

```
var user = doc.Descendants("HttpUser").First().Value;
```

Working [`Code`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6aWviB)